# Calling Javascript (Raphael.js library) from C# codebehind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, raphael, code-behind

I'm trying to call some function from my code behind in C#. I was searching how to do this and was able to call an alert to display when I wanted it to. However, I don't know how to call other things!

This is what I need to call from the code behind:

```
var paper = Raphael("paper1", 800, 800);
var Plan = paper.path("M100, 100 a 50, 50 0 0,1 50, 50 l -50 0 l 0, -50");
Plan.attr({ fill: "#FF6600" });
```

I've tried these on a plain HTML file but I'm not able to use it. I'm also using a master page and most of the examples I've found have been without master pages so I'm pretty lost on this.

Anyone can help?

Comment: How do you get the `alert()` call to work then? You can't really "call" anything on the browser, you can only output a `<script>` block as part of your page that the browser will process. Once your page is done displaying, you can't do that anymore. (AJAX notwithstanding.)

Comment: I'm doing this in the code behind, when a dropdown selected item changes,
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "SymbolError", "<script type='text/javascript' >alert('Error!!!');</script>", false);

Comment: Calling the block of code in your question should work the same way really. What happens when you try it? Does the JS code get output to the browser at all? Are there any errors in the browser's JS console?

Comment: but how do I write all the lines in the place where it says error? I'm kind of a newbie at this, I saw some tutorials but still not an expert :/

Comment: Have you tried just copy-pasting the JS code in place of the `alert()`, then trying to fix any errors that come up?

Comment: I just got it working right now, I made a function that had my code and called it just like the alert(). I was missing a script tag, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Javascript function in the .aspx page and then call the function from code behind like so:

Function in html Code

```
function dostuff()
{
  // code here
}

C# code in code behind
 protected void callmethod()
    {
        StringBuilder oSB = new StringBuilder();
         Type cstype = this.GetType();


        try
        {
            oSB.Append("<script language=javaScript>");
            oSB.Append("dostuff();");
            oSB.Append("</script>");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), oSB.ToString(), false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            oSB = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and the alert worked.
This is what I have now in my aspx file

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js">
    function draw() {
    var paper = Raphael("paper1", 800, 800);
    var Plan = paper.path("M100, 100 a 50, 50 0 0,1 50, 50 l -50 0 l 0, -50");
         }     
 </script>
    <title></title>
</asp:Content>

Comment: In the code behind:

StringBuilder oSB = new StringBuilder();
                Type cstype = this.GetType();
                oSB.Append("<script language=javaScript> src=raphael.js");
                oSB.Append("draw();");
                oSB.Append("</script>");
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), oSB.ToString(), false);

But it's not working! Any ideas?

Comment: <script language=javaScript> src=raphael.js" ?? Why are you adding the reference to the JS File twice?
 StringBuilder oSB = new StringBuilder(); Type cstype = this.GetType(); oSB.Append("<script language='javaScript'>"); oSB.Append("draw();"); 
oSB.Append("</script>"); Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype,Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), oSB.ToString(), false);

This should work.

Comment: Make sure the script loads at the top of the .html / .aspx page this is not best practice but I have seen issues when the page is not completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can only be called on the client side. If you absolutely need to call it from your serverside, you can use a asp:HiddenField's value as a flag for when you need the javascript code executed upon returning, and then run the needed javascript if the requirements are met.

But its not a nice solution, you should probably try to separate the server and the client.

Hope this helps, in any case!

Comment: So what would you suggest to be able to do this? I just need to print some shapes in the screen depending on the status of some items that are taken from a database. I had done that with CSS but stupid IE didn't work with it.